# SaveChanges with SNAPSHOT isolation on EF4

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

We've noticed that all of our INSERT/UPDATE statements are executed with READ UNCOMITTED isolation level using the SaveChanges of EF4.

On our UnitOfWork class this is the code which commits the changes (Inserts/Updates):

```
public int Commit()
{
    return ObjectContextManager.GetObjectContext().SaveChanges();
}
```

We would like that all INSERTS and UPDATES commited using Entity Framework 4 would be commited under SNAPSHOT isolation level.

We've tried surrounding the SaveChanges() with a Scope though it doesn't seem to work (no inserts at all on SQL side).

```
        public int Commit()
        {
            int ret;

            var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(
                // a new transaction will always be created
                TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                // we will allow volatile data to be read during transaction
                new TransactionOptions()
                {
                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Snapshot
                }
            );

            using (scope)
            {
                ret = ObjectContextManager.GetObjectContext().SaveChanges();

                scope.Complete();
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

What are we doing wrong?